# Maximize Scene with FXML - JavaFX2

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm looking for a way to maximize a scene with FXML.
An equivalent to `JFrame.setExtendedState()`. The code `primaryStage.setFullScreen(true)`behaves differently.

```
    Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
    Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
    primaryStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
    primaryStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
    primaryStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
    primaryStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
```

This seems to do what I want , but I'd like to set the size with FXML. To keep GUI code separated from the logic! Thank you in advance, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking, but you could try with

```
primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
```

Comment: Thank You,this is exactly what i want to do , but still i wonder if there is a way to set it in the FXML ?